# How to navigate between different parts of an app within only a part of the screen?

Tags: ios, user-interface, view, uiviewcontroller, navigation

After a few hours of research I couldn’t find anything related to this question.

This is what I am trying to achieve.(demo made with flinto)

[image]

**My Objective**

The bottom half of the screen has a view with 3 buttons on the top represented by shapes . Beneath the buttons are `collectionViews` (with stripes) and further down is a  `view` at the bottom.

Every time a different shape button is clicked I need the view to be modified such that the bottom bar View appears static while the collection views change.  The first (triangular) shape button also has sub buttons (represented by Aa , Bb and Cc)   that can further cause the collection views to change.

**Question**

So my question is how can I go about this ? Shall clicking each shape button present  separate View controllers or can I achieve this within only one view controller where the bottom view is modified every time I click a button.If so how?

I simply need you to point me in the right direction and I could really use some links to useful tutorials .  Thanks!
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [segmented control](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-controls/segmented-controls/)?

Segmented control gives you the option to change the UI based on which segment is selected:

```
@IBAction func indexChanged(_ sender: AnyObject) {
switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
{
    // based on which shape is selected, you can hide/show/change color of other components here
    case 0:
        // triangle is selected
    case 1:
        // hexagon is selected
    case 2:
        //circle is selected
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

The way I would go about this is to use only one view controller, put a stack view inside, and insert multiple segmented control inside the stack view, then manipulate them using the logic above.

Note that if you want to customize the looks of your segmented control, I would create my own subclass of UISegmentedControl where I would configure the UI.

Comment: Thanks for the response Steven. I will follow your recommendation and come back when I have a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is what depends on what kind of functionality you want to implement in your app. Now lets be the short and sweet suppose you want only change the collectionview by the clicking each shape you can achieve it with custom tabbar view using simple `UIView` on single viewController. And if you want your app by adding service call and other UI elements like UITableView and many others at that time I recommended you to go with default `UITabbar`.

Comment: ヅヅ  Thanks for the response .  I cannot go with the UITabbar since I already use it at the bottom . Each tab is supposed to transition to seperate but  visually  similar views that have the same thing going on but perform seperate functions.

Comment: I did upvote your answer but my reputation is so low that it doesn't allow me to add points to yours. : I